# Can I create a text box where the user can't type inside the text box?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, project

I want to know is there a way in html where the  (text box) can be made so that the user can not type in anything in the text box? I have a text box where if you click on it, it displays the datepicker jquery, if a date is chosen then the date is displayed in the text box. So really if a date can be chosen using the datepicker, there is no need for the user to type in the date manually (entering a date manually can lead to human error). So is there a way this can be done?

(This is a new question)

Comment: How valid do you want it to be? Check for things like Feb 30th? March 59th?

Comment: It has to equal like this for example: 18/03/2011. This is so that a user can accidentally type in this in the text box: 18/03/20112 for example or even this 018/03/2011. I have the datepicker jquery so if you pick a date it formats in the text box as they way I want it to format but it is only if the user wants to enter in the date manually then I don't want the user to enter in the date wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try putting the "readonly" attribute on your text field

```
<input type="text" READONLY id="my-date-field"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `dateTextO.dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" == false` means nothing. You could use a regular expression to validate it, like this:

```
var re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}$/;
if(dateTextO.value !== '' && !dateTextO.value.match(re)) {
    errDateMsgO.innerHTML = "Can't Recognise the Date";
} else {
    errDateMsgO.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Edit: quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vuhkw/

However, this won't actually check for real dates, just the format. I'd suggest actually checking server-side for real dates, since the JS can always be spoofed easily.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. I think I will go with php instead because it also states while researching on google that its better using php for checking real dates. Thanks anyway.